# Azure notification and mobile services

Tags: android, ios, cordova, azure, push-notification

I'm using Visual Studio and Cordova to create crossplatform (iOS, Android) app and i'm using also azure hub notification and the mobile services.

It's possible to use just one mobile services with different app and send them different push?

How does it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes technically you can using tags. You can have two different apps using same mobile service and being tagged on notifications hub as two different app type.

So when you need to push something to type 1 apps you specify this tag along with the message to notifications hub.

Let me know if you need more details.